# Cannot Convert Result of Direct SQL Query to List<long> from Generic List

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am trying to select a list of objects from the db with a direct SQL command. `db` is my `dbContext`

```
List<long> ids = db.Database.SqlQuery<List<long>>(sqlCommand).ToList();
```

My query, when tested in SQL (not that visual studio knows this) returns a list of ids, which are of type long. I want to return this list. I use `ToList()` to force execution (since it's [deferred](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15761531/entity-framework-enumerating-sqlquery-result) until enumerated). However, I get a compile error saying that I cannot implicitly convert a generic list to list of type long.

[image]

How do I specify to `List<long>`? This might be a completely stupid question, but I thought it took something of `T` and converted it to a list of `T`, which should be `List<long>` here.

Comment: You are asking for a list of lists of long integers. Change the generic to just long.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple, just make it as follows:

```
List<long> ids = db.Database.SqlQuery<long>(sqlCommand).ToList();
```

Comment: I guess I didn't understand the method fully. Thanks. Will come back to accept after testing. Looks like it's working.

Comment: No problem, glad to help!